# Correctly wrap a tikz figure next to a tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'm trying to find a way to correctly put a table next to a tabular, I found this but changing the value of the first `textwidth` I don't get the result wanted. **I would like to have the two objects centered as they are an unique object**, but as you can see in the image they are more near to the right side. I think my error is with the `minipage` environment, but cannot understand how to solve.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=3cm,% per regolare i bordi a piacimento
heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{amsmath} % per poter usare le lettere calligrafiche
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx} % per inserire immagini
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % per scrivere di fianco alle immagini
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,2.2);
\draw (2,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=2cm];
\draw (0,0) -- (2.6,2) node [above] {T};
\draw (-0.2,2) node [above] {S} -- (3,2) node [right] {$t$};
\draw (0.5,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=37,radius=0.5cm];
\draw (-0.2,-0.2) node {O};
\draw (0.7,0.2) node {$\alpha$};
\draw [dashed] (1.58,1.21) node [right] {P}-- (0,1.21) node [left] {R};
\draw (2.6,0) node [below] {$x_T$};
\draw [red,thick] (0,0) -- (2.6,0);
\draw [dashed] (2.6,2) -- (2.6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
%\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|lllllll}
$\alpha$ & 0\degree & 30\degree & 45\degree & 60\degree & 90\degree & 180\degree & 270\degree\\
\hline
$\tan\alpha$ & 0 & $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ & 1 & $\sqrt{3}$ & $\nexists$ & 0 & $\nexists$\\
\hline
$\cot\alpha$ & $\nexists$ & $\sqrt{3}$ & 1 & $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ & 0 & $\nexists$ & 0
\end{tabular}
%\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make your example compilable? (The `\degree` macro is not defined.)

Comment: Oh sorry, add `\usepackage{gensymb}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `minipage` altogether, set the `baseline` for the `tikzpicture`, and use a single `\centering`, added before `\begin{tikzpicture}`. You can increase the space between diagram and table with `\hspace{<length>}`. Increasing `\arraystretch` might improve the table a bit, giving some extra space between the fractions and the `\hline`s.

(The frame in the image is due to the `showframe` option for `geometry`.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  showframe, % to show the extent of the text area etc.
  a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=3cm,% per regolare i bordi a piacimento
heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\usepackage{tikz} % loads graphicx
\usepackage{gensymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,2.2);
\draw (2,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=2cm];
\draw (0,0) -- (2.6,2) node [above] {T};
\draw (-0.2,2) node [above] {S} -- (3,2) node [right] {$t$};
\draw (0.5,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=37,radius=0.5cm];
\draw (-0.2,-0.2) node {O};
\draw (0.7,0.2) node {$\alpha$};
\draw [dashed] (1.58,1.21) node [right] {P}-- (0,1.21) node [left] {R};
\draw (2.6,0) node [below] {$x_T$};
\draw [red,thick] (0,0) -- (2.6,0);
\draw [dashed] (2.6,2) -- (2.6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{5mm}
\begin{tabular}{l|lllllll}
$\alpha$ & 0\degree & 30\degree & 45\degree & 60\degree & 90\degree & 180\degree & 270\degree\\
\hline
$\tan\alpha$ & 0 & $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ & 1 & $\sqrt{3}$ & $\nexists$ & 0 & $\nexists$\\
\hline
$\cot\alpha$ & $\nexists$ & $\sqrt{3}$ & 1 & $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ & 0 & $\nexists$ & 0
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the packages correction and for the `current bounding` command, now I'm reading about it in the pgfmanual. I can not upvote you cause of my low reputation :c One last thing, is there a simple way to space the figure from the tabular while keeping them in the centered ?

Comment: @soundwave Add for example `\hspace{5mm}` right after `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: You should add some `\extrarowheight`  to the table, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the suggestion, how can I add it (where should I add that command) ?

Comment: @soundwave I did something slightly different, increasing `\arraystretch`. (To add `\extrarowheight`, you need to add `\usepackage{array}` to the preamble, and use `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}` inside the `table` environment.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. wow even better, amazing! thanks very much! and to center the content of every column is sufficient to add `c` in the `\begin{tabular}{l|lllllll}` command ?

Comment: @soundwave `l` means left aligned columns, `c` means centered columns, so yes, replacing the `l`s with `c`s will center the columns. (Tip: if you have multiple columns of the same type after one another, you can use `*{<number of columns>}{<column type>}`, for example `\begin{tabular}{c|*{7}{c}}`.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks again for the patience, you are very gentle to explain all these tricks, you are a pro! Thanks again c:

Comment: @soundwave: you can add `setlength{\extrarowheight}{some value}`either in your preamble, if you want all your tables to have this padding, or inside the table envrinment, before `\begin{tabular}`  for just this table. It isn't necessary  to use it if you increase the value of `\arraystretch`. It is to be used only for for a finer control of the row heights.

Comment: @Bernard thank you for the info, gonna try it!